# VS15 does not recognize files cloned by git after 1803 update

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Last night Win10 did an update to version **1803**.

Since then Visual Studio (2015) cannot compile any new cloned project anymore.
I clone from a gitlab server via Bash on Windows. Old projects that were already on disk before the update still compile without complaining.

It seems that Visual Studio is not able to locate/find the files anymore, since trying to compile gives error messages like:

```
c1xx : fatal error c1083: cannot open source file: ...
```

Does anybody encounter the same problem or has a glue why this could happen?

### Edit:

After some digging it boils down to the problem that the CL.exe compiler seems not to be allowed to read any **sub**directory created by git. However, it has the right to read in the **main** git directory.

### More Edit:

It turns out to be a problem of the Ubuntu subsystems. Directories created via the WSL cannot be read by some programs (in our case the CL.exe) anymore.

What a pity... before the update WSL and VS worked together like a charme!

*Solution so far:* Using the git-Bash until MS fixes the problem...

Comment: By "Bash on Windows", do you mean [git for windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)?

Comment: No, the Ubuntu sub system on Win 10.

Comment: I don't know much about it but I've heard it was not recommended to access files both from Windows and linux subsystem. Let's see however if there is expert opinion. I have added a relevant tag

Comment: @schmitze333 try this https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3118

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this same issue. Based on the link provided by @Biswapriyo, I was able to understand what is causing this issue.

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) recently added support for case-sensitive files/folders. However, when using the `cl.exe` **(c1xx) compiler**, it won't find files in a folder created (or cloned) in the current version of WSL. The reason is that `cl.exe` makes the file and path uppercase. So if your source file is called `main.c` in `c:\tmp`, the compiler looks for `C:\TMP\MAIN.C`. Thus a case-sensitive file match won't work and the compiler "cannot open source file".

To fix this issue, create the file `/etc/wsl.conf` in your WSL environment
Add the following text to `wsl.conf`

```
[automount]

options=case=off
```

I have verified that this fixed the issues that I have seen with the updates to WSL. However, it will break WSL handling filenames that only differ in case that are in the same folder.

Comment: **Thanks** for investigating! Since I switched companies, I may now develop under UNIX and do not have the problem anymore . But I'll forward this solution to my former colleagues.